# Google maps as a Layer inside Geoext3 Tree Panel

Tags: openlayers, google-maps, geoext

I'm trying to load Google Maps as a Layer in Geoext3 tree Panel. I'm using Ol3-Google-Maps. My code is:

```
    var googleLayer = new olgm.layer.Google({
        name: 'Google',
        title: 'Google',
        type: 'base',
        combine: 'true'
    });    


    olMap = new ol.Map({
        layers: [googleLayer, layerorto2016gv, layerlim],
        controls: controls,
        view: new ol.View({
            center: center,
            zoom: 15
        })
    });

    var olGM = new olgm.OLGoogleMaps({map: olMap}); // map is the ol.Map instance
    olGM.activate();               

    mapComponent = Ext.create('GeoExt.component.Map', {
        map: olMap
    });
```

I can't do it works. The result is: "Uncaught TypeError: a.ac is not a function" and I don't see the Tree Panel.
If I remove the lines:
var olGM = new olgm.OLGoogleMaps({map: olMap}); 
        olGM.activate();
The result is: TypeError: a.sf is not a function but I can see de Tree Panel:

[image: Tree Panel]

Does anybody know how to put the Google Layer in the tree panel?

Comment: This may be related to this issue: https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps/issues/37#issuecomment-172858622.  Try using ol3-debug.js to see a human-readable error.

Comment: I have put both ol3gm.js and ol.js and ol.js is included in ol3gm.js. That's was de error. But it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.